# Variance Threshold shape of passed error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shapes, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I have this features which I am trying to reduce based on Variance Threshold:

```
x2.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 120 entries, 0 to 119
Columns: 6083 entries, ADULT.EDUCATION to 1kmrecreacion intelectual / 1kmgeo
dtypes: float64(6083)
memory usage: 5.6 MB
```

I need to retain the features names, so I have obtained this function from another Stackoverflow question:

```
def VarianceThreshold_selector(data):
    columns = data.columns
    selector = VarianceThreshold(.5)
    selector.fit_transform(data)
    labels = [columns[x] for x in selector.get_support(indices=True) if x]
    return pd.DataFrame(selector.fit_transform(data), columns=labels)
```

I apply it:

```
VarianceThreshold_selector(x2)
```

I am getting this error:

> Shape of passed values is (4105, 120), indices imply (4104, 120)

How can I solve it?

Comment: It is difficult to guess what line is throwing that error. You should include more of the traceback or at least tell us what line is specifically causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your function process is wrong. I guess you got only 4104 labels after applying VarianceThreshold, but you tried to pass a pd.dataframe which has 4105 columns.

```
def VarianceThreshold_selector(data):
    columns = data.columns.values.tolist()
    selector = VarianceThreshold(.5)
    newdata = selector.fit_transform(data)
    labels = [columns[x] for x in selector.get_support(indices=True)]
    return pd.DataFrame(newdata, columns=labels)
```

Comment: Should I turn indices = false?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a long function to do that. After fitting the VT estimator, you can call the `.get_support()` attribute which gives a boolean mask. Then, you can use it to subset your original dataframe:

```py
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThresholding

vt = VarianceThresholding(.5)
_ = vt.fit(X_train, y_train)

mask = vt.get_support()

df_reduced = df_original.loc[:, mask]
```